# How do I get angular to work with IE 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angular

I've been working with Angular2 for a while now, and I am currently working on getting my application to cooperate with internet explorer. It runs fine in google chrome. I have gotten it to where it is mostly working in IE though i do notice that the url seems to end up looking in the form of:

```
http://localhost:61209/socialwork#/socialwork#/
```

Where the socialwork#/ substring seems to repeat in the url bar for a very long time.

I am guessing that I may be missing a shim or polyfill, but I am not certain which one.

I do get an error in the console window of IE that says something like this, which I don't find very helpful in this case:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Access is denied.
 ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Access is denied.
 undefined
   "Unhandled Promise rejection:"
   "Access is denied.
"
   "; Zone:"
   "angular"
   "; Task:"
   "Promise.then"
   "; Value:"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      description: "Access is denied.
",
      message: "Access is denied.
",
      name: "Error",
      number: -2147024891
   }
   undefined
```

Also, here are the files I'm loading in to my application.

```
        <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/core.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="/node_modules/classlist-polyfill/src/index.js"></script>
        <script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: are you using transpiling to es5 ?

Comment: I am transpiling to es5.

Comment: have you found a solution for this, I also encountered this on IE9 and I haven't been able to fix it

Comment: The "access denied" error isn't the cause, it's the result of the super long url. Fix whatever is causing your path to be repeated and you'll fix the error.